# printing while process works in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to print out, say a period, for every second (or whatever unit) a process works (like compiling a java program (note: javac is called from my python program))?

Comment: Are you using `subprocess.Popen` to call `javac`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blueprint:

- start your process using subprocess.Popen(...)
- Popen.poll() for checking the state of the process
- use something like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.3-dev for rendering a progressbar (or search on PyPI for something similar) while polling